# Out-of-domain generalization

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, image-recognition, generalization

Given $X$ the space of all $N \times N$-pixel images and $I=\{$airplane,clock,axe,...$\}$ a set of labels.

An image classification task is generally concerned to learn a map
$$F:X \rightarrow I$$
Let's look at the examples of pictures below taken from [2](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ICCV_2019/papers/Peng_Moment_Matching_for_Multi-Source_Domain_Adaptation_ICCV_2019_paper.pdf). The rows classify the domain of the picture. I.e. a real plane or a sketched plane. Out-of-domain generalization deals with the question of whether it is possible to train a NN e.g. on real photos of planes such that it will also be able to classify sketched pictures of a plane.

---

I have a hard time understanding these domains. My question is the following: Can I think of each domain as a disjoint set in $X$. Let's say $X_1$ are all sketched planes and $X_2$ all real planes. Then $X_1 \cap X_2 = \emptyset$. If not, what is the right way to think about domains?

[image]

Comment: seems like it to me. Are you overthinking it? They've obviously said the domains are sketch, real, quickdraw, painting, infograph, clipart, maybe more

Comment: i.e. another set of classes orthogonal to the first set. Which is literally what is drawn in this chart

Comment: Can you please put your **specific question** in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interpret the image as follows:

- Each *column* represent a **class** (or category) of an object, for example what you denote with $X_1$ and $X_2$ are classes not domains which can overlap.
- Instead, each *row* is a **domain**, i.e. the broader, more general, and higher-level (semantically) concept that can include multiple categories even partially. In fact, the domain "quickdraw" contains objects that belong to the same classes of the domain "real": you still have plane, clock, etc but the conceptual representation is different. I cannot claim that domains are mutually exclusive, maybe they are when there is no ambiguity.

For example, a human can interpret a sketch as a plane (instead of as a set of lines and curves) thanks to its higher-level cognitive capabilities that allow, at the same time, to see something in its building blocks (e.g. the lines; which is kind of low-level understanding) and as a whole (giving it some semantics and meaning.)

Take as an example an image classifier, you train it on images from the real domain. The classifier, in order to show out-of-domain (OOD) generalization should correctly classify images from the quickdraw domain: if so it achieved OOD generalization on that domain. In order to do this, the model should (at least): 1) not adapt to the training domain (which translates to almost zero *overfitting* and plenty of *regularization*), 2) ignore the noise in the images (*robustness*), and 3) capture high-level features that describe the image semantically, i.e. it should capture the concept that an image describes but also capture the same on OOD images.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am really interested in whether the domains are mutually exclusive in the input space. If so, do you agree that OOD is actually about extrapolating a function?

Comment: Well, extrapolation can be a result of OOD generalization but it can also happen within the same domain: I mean if your training data belong to domain $D$ and are bounded in a range $(a,b)$ (simply because the data can't always represent the whole domain) and the model shows good performance either with points below $a$ and $b$, then it achieved extrapolation but within the same training domain, i.e. $D$. Perhaps, OOD generalization implies *adaptation* to a new domain with zero samples (or in *zero-shot* regime.)